# Deleting a template after indexing documents

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, aws-elasticsearch

I have one index i elastic search and it is created using a template. I am thinking to stop using templates moving forward and convert to attributes in class using NEST.

Is it OK to delete the template from server and continue indexing documents in the same index?

I know that an index is tied to a template which started, not sure where to find information if deleting the template consequent documents indexed will adhere to the new rules via attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its okay to delete a template once done. But why would you want to delete it?  Index templates can stay there and be applied to indices based on `index_patterns` so it doesnt affect any other index schema.

> " I am thinking to stop using templates moving forward and convert to
>   attributes in class using NEST"

I dont think you should stop using index templates. Its easier to maintain and to define analyzers, synonyms, etc.

Also, index templates are only applied when an index is created to define the schema. Here's a [note from the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

> Templates are only applied at index creation time. Changing a template
>   will have no impact on existing indices. When using the create index
>   API, the settings/mappings defined as part of the create index call
>   will take precedence over any matching settings/mappings defined in
>   the template.

Comment: OK, I get this point and it was my initial thoughts hence I followed using templates. Maybe this is a separate question but now for some documents I use one constant index e.g. users-all and so it is created with the template deployed, how do I deal schema change moving forward with applying new template to already created index?

Comment: You cannot change existing field mappings for already indexed data. However, if there’s a change. Update existing index template and reindex all the existing data to new index to apply new mapping changed. To keep the search endpoint constant, you can use alias that doesn’t change. So any change to index name should not matter when you reindex. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I will create a new question to have it in SO for other devs as well and elaborate more on the subject of how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698644/update-field-mappings-template-in-created-index-under-an-alias