# Update field mappings template in created index under an alias

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, aws-elasticsearch

I have deployed a template in AWS ElasticSearch named `users-version-1-order-1`, and indexed data under `users-all` index which is searchable via `users` alias.

So, all documents are always indexed and updated in `users-all`, how do I deal with schema change moving forward with applying a new template version? e.g. PUT `users-version-2-order-2` and apply it to `users-all` index.

[UPDATE]

```
{
  "index_patterns": "users*",
  "order": 6,
  "version": 6,
  "aliases": {
    "users": {}
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "keyword" },
        "emailAddress": { "type": "keyword" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to show your actual template definitions.

Comment: Not sure if it really helps, it's pretty simple for now. Updated question

Comment: I'd avoid doing manual version control on ES and update the same index template with new mappings and have git or something do versioning. But if you have to then read this : https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Comment: I will check it out for sure, still trying to find the best strategy for this "problem".